# Pointing subdomain to specific url in Django

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, virtualhost, subdomain

I have a Django site, working on mod_wsgi and Apache. (eg, example.com) I made a subdomain (eg, info.example.com) and want to point it to app in the existing project. Is it possible, that I have one urls.py file, and example.com/info and info.example.com point to the same view in Django project (without duplicating the whole project in different directory)?

If so, how can I do it? Currently the example.com virtalhost config for the existing project looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com

   DocumentRoot /srv/www/Example/Pub_html

   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/Example/example.wsgi
   <Directory /srv/www/Example/Example>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/Example/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/Example/favicon.ico
   ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE*: I did a quick fix here by creating another Django project which shares database tables and template folder with the existing one. It works, but it's not really DRY :)

Comment: You probably want to add a RewriteRule, which would internally transform the info.example.com to example.com/info. Those are notoriously difficult to write, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with a reverse proxy, I reckon.  If you have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_html` available, try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
    ServerName info.example.com

    ProxyPass       /  http://example.com/info

    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    <Location />
        ProxyPassReverse /info/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap /info/ /
    </Location>
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://example.com/info /
</VirtualHost>
```

the details may not be quite right, so let me know if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I got it working with just the ProxyPass line. With the full file it was throwing error 330 in google chrome and I had [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(1) failed in child 14565 for worker proxy:reverse; [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(0) failed in child 14565 for worker http://example.com/info